# What is the logic behind this backtesting code in R

Tags: r, quant-trading-strategies, returns, backtesting

I am new to R and I have found this simple backtesting code and can you explain me what is happening here.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

s <- get(getSymbols('SPY'))["2012::"]
s$sma20 <- SMA(Cl(s) , 20)
s$position <- ifelse(Cl(s) > s$sma20 , 1 , -1)
myReturn <- lag(s$position) * dailyReturn(s)
charts.PerformanceSummary(cbind(dailyReturn(s),myReturn))
```

[image]

I know the code uses this strategy

```
    Buy    
    close > SMA20
    sell
    close < SMA20
```

But I have doubts especially in these lines

```
s$position <- ifelse(Cl(s) > s$sma20 , 1 , -1) 
myReturn <- lag(s$position) * dailyReturn(s)
charts.PerformanceSummary(cbind(dailyReturn(s),myReturn))
```

`s$position <- ifelse(Cl(s) > s$sma20 , 1 , -1)` if close price is greater than 20 days moving average then `s$postion=1` else `s$postion=-1`, Buy why assign 1 and -1? why calculating dailyreturns and whats is happing with myReturn,cbind()? Also can you explain this results https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1h7E.png

Comment: Beware, this code would produce wrong results for the short side as I explained it at the last paragraph in [this](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21075/is-there-a-good-backtesting-package-in-r/21106#21106) post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When position = 1, then you are long the S&P ETF. When position is -1, your portfolio consist of a short position of -1 S&P ETF. 
You will therefore have a vector like $Pos = (1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1, \ldots)$, that will give you the evolution of your portfolio.

Your returns are then the daily returns on the S&P multiplied by your position.

Cbind is the command for binding two vector together by their columns. So you take the evolution of the S&P (dailyReturns) and column-bind them with the evolution of your portfolio (myReturn), and plot them using the PerformanceAnalytics package.